# How to access view in addTextChangedListener?

Tags: android, android-studio, addtextchangedlistener

I want to add a method where passing view as parameter below is the code on directly adding somemethod(view) shows error.

```
abc.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
   somemethod(view); // this is where I stuck
  }
 }
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}
});
.....
somemethod(View view) {}
```

Comment: What is `view` here

Comment: What is the error you're getting

Comment: What's the error? what's view? What's somemethod?

Comment: the error is 'cannot find the symbol view'

Comment: somemethod is a simple method with parameter View view and it is used in multiple blocks of code.It is inside of public class MainActivity and out side of protected void onCreate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private View view;

    private MyTextWatcher(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        //access view
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        //access view
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        //access view
    }
}
```

**Add Listener to View**

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(editText));
```

Comment: we can make `MyTextWatcher` abstract and do not implement methods, keep `View` object public. so `TextView` can be accessed inside implementation  and implementation can be changed for each `TextView`

Answer (score 0):

I guess Your question is little vague. If you are running this code from OnCreate(), You can get the view as follows , else if it is from other onclick methods, view will be available as parameter.

```
final View view = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```